# Send key board event (space) to process in python

Tags: python, subprocess, keyboard-events, psutil

I want to send a space to the process, the process itself is being searched for normally, but I can’t send a space

Comment: can this be done in any language? It is a specific process in which I know the pid

Comment: can i get the current active window through psutils